# Movie about a man whose shadow didn’t follow him

Tags: story-identification

A few years ago I watched a movie trailer, but now I can’t remember the name.

It was about someone whose shadow didn't follow him. It was like a regular shadow, but it wasn't doing the exact things that the man was doing.

For example, the man opened the refrigerator while holding a bottle of milk, but the shadow stood behind him without doing anything.
There was also another scene; the shadow's hand came out of the wall.
The movie was not animated and the language was English.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of the film "The shadow" but I don't think there is a refigerator scene there. Did it seem like it was in the 30s settingwise or modern?

Comment: Live action or animated? Did it seem to be a recent work? What language was it in?

Comment: I don't know the year of the film but it didn't seem old.It guess it was filmed after 2009

Comment: It wasn't animated.English was the languge of the film.

Answer (score 2):

### This is the aptly-named movie [*The Shadow People*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_People_(film))

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RszVo4me9qc) is the link to a Youtube trailer that includes the scene you mention.

[image]

This movie features the "shadow people," nocturnal nasties that kill people without leaving a trace. Interestingly, [some people](http://beforeitsnews.com/paranormal/2013/04/new-film-shadow-people-causes-a-stir-in-the-paranormal-community-2450004.html) believe this to be a real-life phenomenon.

Better stock up on RnA drops!